# Pandas Return Only Repeated Results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the columns:

```
UserID, Date, (other columns that we can ignore here)
```

I'm trying to select out only users that have visited on multiple dates. I'm currently doing it with `groupby(['UserID', 'Date'])` and a for loop, where I drop users with only one result, but I feel like there is a much better way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exact format of output you want to get, but you can count distinct Dates inside each UserID and get all where this count > 1 (like `having count(distinct Date) > 1` in SQL):

```
>>> df
                 Date  UserID
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00       1
1 2013-01-02 00:00:00       2
2 2013-01-02 00:00:00       2
3 2013-01-02 00:00:00       1
4 2013-01-02 00:00:00       3
>>> g = df.groupby('UserID').Date.nunique()
>>> g
UserID
1         2
2         1
3         1
>>> g > 1
UserID
1          True
2         False
3         False
dtype: bool
>>> g[g > 1]
UserID
1         2
```

you see that you get `UserID = 1` as a result, it's the only user visited on multiple dates

Comment: `Series.nunique()` is slower than `len(Series.unique())`, can we consider this as a bug?

Comment: @HYRY interesting, have to do some tests

Comment: Hmm, this is basically what I originally tried, but I'm getting an `ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0` error, maybe its because my 'Date' field is a string representing the date, and not a proper date. I'll try some things and update.

Answer (score 0):

To count unique date counts for every UserID:

```
df.groupby("UserID").Date.agg(lambda s:len(s.unique()))
```

The you can drop users with only one count.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of adding another answer, you can also use indexing with list comprehension

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'UserID' : [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5], 'Data': np.random.rand(7)})
DF.ix[[row for row in DF.index if list(DF.UserID).count(DF.UserID[row])>1]]
```

This might be as much work as your for loop, but its just another option for you to consider....

Comment: I assumed you would search for multiple entries by User ID, not date. Is that right? Perhaps this is not appropraite if you users can be visited twice on the same date and you are not interested in them...